# Redirect customers to login page from home page in Magento 2

Tags: magento2.3, custom, home-page, redirect-url, customer-login

I want to redirect my store customers to custom login page when a customer visits my magento 2 store url. The customer could not access the site till he login to the store.

How could I do that in Magento 2.3.x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve this. Create [**an observer**](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/events-and-observers.html#observers) on events `controller_action_predispatch` and then using customer session `\Magento\Customer\Model\Session` **check every URL and redirect to  Customer login page.**

- Create first `events.xml` where we can defined observer for your work.File location: `app/code/{Vendor}/{ModuleName}/etc/frontend/events.xml`
- Create an observer class for checking customer login and redirect to
  logo page.`app/code/{Vendor}/{ModuleName}/Observer/ControllerActionPredispatch.php`

### events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="controller_action_predispatch">
        <observer name="check_customer_session_login"
                  instance="{Vendor}\{ModuleName}\Observer\ControllerActionPredispatch"  />
    </event>
</config>
```

### ControllerActionPredispatch.php

```
<?php
namespace {Vendor}\{ModuleName}\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;

class ControllerActionPredispatch implements ObserverInterface
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Url
     */
    private $customerUrl;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
     */
    private $customerSession;
    /**
     * @var LoggerInterface
     */
    private $logger;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Url $customerUrl,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        LoggerInterface $logger
    ){
        $this->customerUrl = $customerUrl;
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        /** @var Action $controller */
        $action = $observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction();
        $request = $observer->getEvent()->getRequest();
        $request->getRouteName();
        $this->logger->info($request->getRouteName());
        $loginUrl = $this->customerUrl->getLoginUrl();

        if (($request->getRouteName()!== 'customer') &&
            (!$this->customerSession->authenticate($loginUrl))
        ) {
            $action->getActionFlag()->set('', $action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I want to redirect to custom login page 'customer/account/custom-login/'. Is it possible using above method?

Comment: yes, it can do ` $this->customerUrl->getLoginUrl()`. Gives the Login url

Comment: i used the above method it gives me HTTP ERROR 500.

Comment: please check the log files for 500 error, The code is test on 2.3. and it working fine